# PageMethod and viewstate problem

Tags: asp.net

i was trying to access viewstate from pagemethod. i know that pagemethod invoke a static method in code behind so that is why viewstate can't be access from static method but is there any wayout for this solution. i dont want to use session instead of viewstate.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're in the wrong way.

ViewState is a way of storing values so a control or page would hold data across web requests.

Have you considered using ASP.NET Callback API? Maybe this could be your solution.

Check this article:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178208.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use Viewstate in a PageMethod. Neither a Session. This method runs completely independend of the ASP.NET page otherwise.

Comment: Session can be use from PageMethod.HttpContext.Current.Session["data"] = "Hello"; i used it but ViewState is not.